#  Django:How to let 3rd party sites access images on your server.(limited access i.e. only to that folder)

Tags: python, django, url-routing, urllib2

I am working in Django.I am trying to connect my website to Facebook. What i want to do is

1)Send post_data

```
post_data = [('access_token',access_token), ('message', message), ('link', some_link),('picture',internal_server_path_of_image)
```

2)`urllib2.urlopen(graph_url, urllib.urlencode(post_data))`

What this should do is post that data on the facebook profile of a user. But i am unable to access "internal_server_path_of_image". Is there anyway in which i can make a particular folder on my server available to the site ? i.e. the images on that folder should be accessible from outside.
for e.g. I have folder site_name/project/images/photos.png
on the server some_server.dreamhost.com/site_name/project/images/photos.png. Now i want to access this image somehow.

Is the question clear ? or do I need to add a few things ?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to access" a particular image? Is the problem in your webserver's configuration? Can you see it if you browse there with your browser?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco The image is internal file on the server. I want to be able to make this file available ..

Comment: Then what you need to do change is your webserver's configuration. Is the image in your document root (usually /var/www/)? If it is, you might yet have to edit your configuration to allow access to the image. You could also use Django's ImageField as they provide a method to get the correct URL automatically.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco can you please elaborate on this point ? exactly which configuration will i have to change ? I am using django image field for this..

Comment: Well, what webserver are you using? Where is your image stored, is it uploaded through your Django App? If that is the case, what does your STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT, MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT Django settings refer to? In any case, where is your image file exactly located?

Comment: I am using using dreamhost tohost my site.

Where is your image stored, is it uploaded through your Django App?
It is stored at  `/templates/media/images` (Please look at the experts from settings file)
And yes it is uploaded by my django App.
`MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost/media/'`
`MEDIA_ROOT      = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates/media/')`
# used as starting points for various other paths
`DJANGO_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(django.__file__))
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)`

Comment: # So that the apps can be referenced without the project name
`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, ''))`

Comment: We have not used STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT for the storing of images. Will these settings help in the above said tasks

Comment: Your media url points your clients to their own computers when they want to download your media, so it's not going to work. You should change your media url to that it points to the url of your templates/media/ directory on your webserver. You will need to expose it in your webserver config.

Comment: @Thomas i have come with a solution. As you had pointed out that the imagefield gives us the url of the image. That was true. What iam doing know is passing that url. At that url i have written a controller method. This method simply renders the image and returns it. This gives access to the facebook api to get the required image from my server.
`def test(request,name):
    name = str(name)+".jpg"
    url = "Users/admin/workspace/bolt/templates/media/images/photos/"
    full =url+name 
    image_data = open(full, "rb").read()
    return HttpResponse(image_data, mimetype="image/png")`

Comment: @ThomasOrozco thanks for your valuable inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come with a solution. As people had pointed out that the imagefield gives us the url of the image. That was true, what i am doing now is passing that url. At that url i have written a controller method. This method simply renders the image and returns it. This gives access to the facebook api to get the required image from my server.

```
def test(request,name): 
   name = str(name)+".jpg" 
   url = "Users/admin/workspace/bolt/templates/media/images/photos/" 
   full = url+name image_data = open(full, "rb").read() 
   return HttpResponse(image_data, mimetype="image/png")
```

Hope this helps others